# Исходящий траффик OpenVPN через Socks прокси

Tags: openvpn

Пытаюсь реализовать следующую цепочку:

**Client -> OpenVPN -> Socks -> WWW**

Ситуацию усложняет несколько копий OpenVPN на сервере, которые слушают разные порты. У каждого инстанса выделена сеть своя приватных айпи для клиентов, скажем 192.168.0.0

В итоге получается:

Client 1 -> OpenVPN 1 (**192.168.1.0**) -> Socks 1 -> WWW

Client 2 -> OpenVPN 2 (**192.168.2.0**) -> Socks 2 -> WWW

Были попытки с помощью фаервола роутить траффик через входящий порт, но они не увенчались успехом.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31030/connect-through-two-vpn-clients - надеюсь вам поможет. См. ответ от LSerni - человек всё расписал довольно понятно.

Comment: Особенно здесь:  *This is done through routing rules on the client. For example, you might receive address 192.168.42.17/24 on VPN1, and address 192.168.77.13/24 on VPN2. If you tried to link with host .42.33, you would go through VPN1, and VPN2 would know nothing of it.* и далее...